# How to modify the endnotes package so as to reduce the spacing between the vertical line and the endnotes?

Tags: endnotes

I was able to modify the notes heading of endnotes by using the following commands from another stack exchange answer:

```
\def\enoteheading{\par\kern2\baselineskip%
                  \footnoterule%
                  \kern1\baselineskip}
```

But I would also like to reduce the vertical spacing bewtween the horizontal line and where the notes start

[image: I want to reduce the spacing highlighted in blue]

Can someone please help me to achieve that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code snippet compilable.

Comment: although this would really be better with a small compilable example, the obvious change to try is to reduce the `\kern` below the rule.  you might try `\kern.5\baselineskip` or some other appropriate value.

Comment: Hello @barbarabeeton, thank you for your solution. What you suggested solves the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

without an actual example, enough information was given to address this question.

let's look at the definition shown in the question:

```
\def\enoteheading{\par\kern2\baselineskip%
                  \footnoterule%
                  \kern1\baselineskip}
```

`\par` makes sure that processing is in vertical mode, necessary for the `\kern`s
to be applied in the proper direction.

two kerns are applied, one above and the other below the rule.  all
instructions proceed downward in the vertical direction.

the amount of each kern is specified in terms of the `\baselineskip`.  for the
upper kern, this is the equivalent of two blank lines, and one line for the lower.
but it's not necessary to specify integral values -- distances can be expressed
with decimal values as well.

thus the obvious solution is to set the value of the lower kern to something
less than 1.  `.5` is a reasonable place to start, and this can be adjusted by
experimentation.